# add_post_meta only adding 1 character

Tags: post-meta

I am trying to make a form that auto posts without needing to be signed in. So far I'm testing with dummy data, but I'm running into trouble with the add_post_meta part. It seems to only be adding 1 character (the 2nd one for some reason). This is my code:

```
<?php
$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags('testing'),
    'post_author' => 5,
    'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
    'post_category' => array( 135 ),
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_type' => 'portal',
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

add_post_meta($post_id, 'portal_tl_name', 'karen');
add_post_meta($post_id, 'portal_tl_brokerage', 'coquitlam');
?>
```

When I load the page with this script, it add's the post, but in the 2 sections with meta data, I'm only seeing:

a
o

I'm not sure why. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code looks fine, and it isn't happening to me when I run the exact same code in my install. What other code is on this page? How are you displaying the meta data - is it possible that the issue is occuring there?

Comment: @TimMalone I'm using the Post Meta plugin to create the portal post type. And then adding custom field textboxes to the editor for that post type. That is where I only see 1 character showing up.